# Client server synchronization with offline support

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization, operational-transform, share.js

What I'm trying to do is a synchronization of json objects on the client side with help of the server. When the client is not able to connect to the server it should fall back to a locally stored backup of the most recent objects.

I have tried ShareJS for this and so far I can't really connect to the server. All the examples kind of work server side as far as I understand.

How do I connect to a remote ShareJS server with different clients (with authentication)?

Or maybe are there better solutions than ShareJS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know ShareJS. Due the lack of Code no one can help you here. As an alternative you could try http://hood.ie

- they have a good documentation too, which you should read ;)